# is BIGSERIAL threadsafe in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as below in postgres,

```
create table test
(
    empId BIGSERIAL,
    empName text
)
```

I want to know if the serial number generated by BIGSERIAL for every insert is **thread safe**?

Suppose if two thread are trying to do insert as below,

```
insert into test(empName) values('abc');
```

is there any possibility that we can see two entries in table with **same empId** ?

We are seeing a scenario in our setup where there are duplicate serial numbers in postgres table.

Comment: This is one of the guarantees every RDBMS gives you (Transactional Integrity)

Comment: Yes. correct. But how come i am seeing two entries in my table. Can there be any scenario where it can go wrong?

Comment: There is no unique constraint on the column, so you could create the duplicates manually, eg: `insert into test(empid, empname) select empid, empname from test;`

Comment: @codeflush.dev BIGSERIAL and SERIAL are outside of transaction control, so transactional integrity is not involved here.

Comment: @wildplasser.. i dont have such manual inserts . i have checked the code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel .. u mean to say SERIAL and BIGSERIAL is not thread safe? .. this issue has happened now for the first time. the code base is 3 years old.

Comment: @vinodhy No SERIAL and BIGSERIAL are atomic, and thus thread-safe. What I said is they are outside of transaction control,  as in a rollback will not decrement the sequence to its previous value.

Comment: Well, maybe you restored from a backup, and somehow forgot to reset the sequence correctly after the restore? Or you attempted to restore using threads *concurrently*, resetting the sequence after each "batch* ? (which is what Java people often think to be *faster*)

Comment: BTW: are you using an ORM, for instance Hibernate?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if the serial number generated by BIGSERIAL for every insert is thread safe?

Yes, absolutely. A bigserial uses a sequence in the background.

This is what [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) has to say about obtaining the next sequence value

> This is done atomically: even if multiple sessions execute nextval concurrently, **each will safely receive a distinct sequence value**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you see duplicate numbers, this means some inserts were done **overriding** the sequence generation, e.g.

```
insert into test (empid, empname) values (42, 'Arthur');
```

To avoid that, make `empid` the primary key, then at least you get an error when you try to insert a duplicate.

That's one of the reasons it is [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) to use `identity` columns in modern Postgres versions:

```
create table test
(
  empid bigint primary key generated always as identity,
  empName text not null
);
```

That way, providing an explicit value for `empid` would yield an error - even if it wasn't a duplicate (yet).

Comment: There are no such manual inserts . i have checked the code. the code base is 3 years old. We encountered the issue today.

Comment: @vinodhy: then maybe someone reset the sequence or the inserts were done manually outside of your code. But the sequence will never emit the same value twice unless it was tampered with. The real question is however: why there isn't a primary (or unique) key constraint on that column?

Comment: yes.. primary key is not there.. that is missing..Adding that will avoid duplicate entries. But i was wondering how duplicate serial numbers got generated. BIGSERIAL should never allow that..  There are no manual inserts/no sequence reset for sure.

Comment: We are seeing another issue where a table had a primary key constraint. But still duplicate entries are observed in the table. I have created a seperate thread for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216554/postgres-duplicate-primary-key-entries-in-table

Answer (score 0):

The usage you show is safe as long as **everyone** does it that way.

It is possible to come up with other uses which are unsafe.  For example, if you manually ask for the next value and then the server crashes very shortly after, that value might be issued again after the crash.  If your app memorized the value it was issued before the crash and then opens a new connection after the crash and writes the memorized value into the database over the new connection, you can get duplicate values that way.  You should really only use the value on the same connection that issued it.

Comment: "*if you manually ask for the next value and then the server crashes very shortly after, that value might be issued again after the crash*" - no it won't. Once the value was generated it will never be used again (wrapping or manual messing around with the sequence excluded)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The WAL generated by the issuance is flagged as being asyncronous.  There is no interlock to force that WAL to hit disk prior to the value being returned to the user.  So if there is a crash before that WAL hits disk, it won't know not to re-issue the value after the crash.